Why does the amplitude of my filter seem to increase as the poles move away from the unit circle?
I copied some plotting code from Scipy, generated my own filter and it seems that the closer the poles are to the origin (tweaked by pole_scaling) the larger the gain, which, unless I'm forgetting something, should not be the case...
yet I fail to see how I messed up the one line I wrote to generate the coefficients a,b
from scipy.signal import zpk2tf,freqz
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
pole_scaling = 0.9
b,a = zpk2tf([np.exp(-1j*2*np.pi*k/1200) for k in np.arange(-120,121,5)],[np.exp(-1j*2*np.pi*k/1200)*pole_scaling  for k in np.arange(-100,101,5)],0.0001)
w, h = freqz(b, a, 1000)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(w, 20 * np.log10(abs(h)))
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xlabel('Frequency [radians / second]')
ax.set_ylabel('Amplitude [dB]')
ax.grid(which='both', axis='both')

As I recall, you get the gain for some frequency theta by taking the absolute value of the polynomial in b divided by the polynomial in a where z=e^{j*theta}...

Welcome to our forum! Poles with the same Q are indeed on a circle in the Z-plane, but it's not a circle that's centered at the origin. Your results are correct, but your expectations are wrong.
